# Multiple app instance logging

Tags: java, networking, logging

My application is allowed to have multiple instances running and I would like to log events from all running instances. I am currently using java util logging's socket handler to centralize the logging process. When the first instance starts, it also a starts a new socket server thread. The problem is when this instance is closed, the server thread is also closed and log method (from another instance) throws exception. I am not thinking to run it as a separate process (using Runtime exec) because I would not be able to shut it down gracefully from my application.

So is there a way where another instance on seeing the server down, create a new server thread? This similar approach is being done in H2 database AUTO_SERVER mode where it automatically switches to client and server mode.

So any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [Logback's prudent mode](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudent).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might need a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29) to initialize the socket server if it is not already running:

Comment: I think the questioner is using multiple jvm's.

Comment: Yes. I am running multiple jvm's. So singleton is not a solution.

Comment: could you use [junique](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/junique/index.php) then? I've never used it but it seems like that's the sort of thing it was designed to.

Comment: But my app needs to run multiple instances. Each instance configured differently. So junique is not an option either.